# Registration of windows shell namespace folder view extension for particular file extension

Tags: c++, windows, registry, explorer, windows-shell

I have some windows namespace shell extension for folder view. I want to use it for user interaction with files having particular file extension. Those files are created by other my application.

How to perform proper it's proper registration in windows registry. Should I add some key for file extension with CLSID of my extension and extension itself or something else?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must register in this registry locations:

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.yourextension]
@="CLSID\\{Your namespace extension CLSID}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{Your namespace extension CLSID}]
@="Test File"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{Your namespace extension CLSID}\CLSID]
@="{Your namespace extension CLSID}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{Your namespace extension CLSID}\DefaultIcon]
@="yourdll.dll,0"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{Your namespace extension CLSID}\Implemented Categories]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{Your namespace extension CLSID}\Implemented Categories\{00021490-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{Your namespace extension CLSID}\InProcServer32]
@="yourdll.dll"
"ThreadingModel"="Apartment"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{Your namespace extension CLSID}\shell]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{Your namespace extension CLSID}\shell\explore]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{Your namespace extension CLSID}\shell\explore\command]
@=hex(2):25,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,52,00,6f,00,6f,00,74,00,25,\
  00,5c,00,45,00,78,00,70,00,6c,00,6f,00,72,00,65,00,72,00,2e,00,65,00,78,00,\
  65,00,20,00,2f,00,65,00,2c,00,2f,00,69,00,64,00,6c,00,69,00,73,00,74,00,2c,\
  00,25,00,49,00,2c,00,25,00,4c,00,00,00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{Your namespace extension CLSID}\shell\explore\ddeexec]
@="[ExploreFolder(\"%l\", %I, %S)]"
"NoActivateHandler"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{Your namespace extension CLSID}\shell\explore\ddeexec\application]
@="Folders"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{Your namespace extension CLSID}\shell\explore\ddeexec\ifexec]
@="[]"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{Your namespace extension CLSID}\shell\explore\ddeexec\topic]
@="AppProperties"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{Your namespace extension CLSID}\shell\find]
"SuppressionPolicy"=dword:00000080

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{Your namespace extension CLSID}\shell\find\command]
@=hex(2):25,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,52,00,6f,00,6f,00,74,00,25,\
  00,5c,00,45,00,78,00,70,00,6c,00,6f,00,72,00,65,00,72,00,2e,00,65,00,78,00,\
  65,00,00,00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{Your namespace extension CLSID}\shell\find\ddeexec]
@="[FindFolder(\"%l\", %I)]"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{Your namespace extension CLSID}\shell\find\ddeexec\application]
@="Folders"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{Your namespace extension CLSID}\shell\find\ddeexec\topic]
@="AppProperties"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{Your namespace extension CLSID}\shell\open]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{Your namespace extension CLSID}\shell\open\command]
@=hex(2):25,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,52,00,6f,00,6f,00,74,00,25,\
  00,5c,00,45,00,78,00,70,00,6c,00,6f,00,72,00,65,00,72,00,2e,00,65,00,78,00,\
  65,00,20,00,2f,00,69,00,64,00,6c,00,69,00,73,00,74,00,2c,00,25,00,49,00,2c,\
  00,25,00,4c,00,00,00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{Your namespace extension CLSID}\shell\open\ddeexec]
@="[ViewFolder(\"%l\", %I, %S)]"
"NoActivateHandler"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{Your namespace extension CLSID}\shell\open\ddeexec\application]
@="Folders"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{Your namespace extension CLSID}\shell\open\ddeexec\ifexec]
@="[]"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{Your namespace extension CLSID}\shell\open\ddeexec\topic]
@="AppProperties"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{Your namespace extension CLSID}\ShellFolder]
"Attributes"=dword:680001a0
```

For possible Attributes values see [SFGAO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762589%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) values.

Also dont forgot add your CLSID to the Approved shell extensions.